# hover trigger called just after multilevelpushmenu first toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i use jquery, bootstrap, fa, normalize and **jquery.multilevelpushmenu.js v2.1.4** that provide side-menu multi level, i'm tring to combined hover operation with that menu, and the hover call just after first toggle menu, never seen this behavior before.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.content gallery-item').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.content  img-title').fadeIn(300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.content .img-title').fadeOut(0);
    });

});
</script>
```

Here what i have tried:

1. isolate to minimum script / JS-libs
2. tried to call to dest hover tag with more specific css selector

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shdr/dk15842z/) of the complete scenario.

How can i make it work onload?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? I am unable to get it. You mean you want to open the menu on load?

Comment: @hunzaboy, i want the hover to work onload not depends after i toggle the menu' if you'll look on the JSFiddle i linked you will see that it not work until i toggle the menu first. i dont know why.

Comment: you are referring the hover on the menu items? the way the items are displaying when you toggle

Comment: Oh ok got it now :) you were referencing to the items in the content area.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS** way to fix the issue is to give the element a lower **z-index**. As the menu container is overlapping it that's why it is unable to target the element properly.

This code should fix it.

```
.multilevelpushmenu_wrapper{
min-width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I mean the side-menu check again

Comment: Please select it as the answer if it solves your issue. :)

Comment: @shdr , Well the width of 100% was overlapping the content. It didn't needed 100% width.